# How to add manually a button on a DataGrid's end in pure XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I've got a DataGrid with some columns:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}, Mode=OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
     //9 DataGridTextColumn more
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I'd like to append a button at the end of the DataGrid. Regardless how many rows there are, the button should be "the last row" with colspan over all columns. I've tried something, but it didnt work:

```
//</DataGrid.Columns>
<local:MyRecord Date="" ....>
    <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button1_Clicked" >Load More</Button>
</local:MyRecord>
```

The code behind Looks like this:

```
public class MyRecord{
    public string Date{ get; set;} 
    //...
}
```

How is it possible to append/add a button at the end of my DataGrid? Is it possible in pure XAML?

Comment: Why to use a DataGrid? Why not use a StackPannel with your DataGrid and a Button?

Comment: As @MorgoZ says, why not change to an implementation that better fits with the way the controls work - rather than trying to shoehorn something into that isn't really appropriate. A `DataGrid` is a great way of displaying many items all of the same type. A button isn't the same type as the rest of the items in your grid, so doesn't really 'fit'.

Comment: you need to imporve the question if you want help, 'I've tried something, but it didnt work:' is not very helpful, you need to explain why it didn't work.  You need to post the complete XAML for the DataGrid

Comment: There is no existing feature that allows you to add a footer to DataGrid. But you can try referring these - http://thibaud60.blogspot.in/2008/10/wpftoolkit-datagrid-with-footer-and.html or this one - http://wpfextendeddatagrid.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Row%20Footer

Comment: @MorgoZ Well, thats a brilliant idea!

Comment: @Mashton thank you very much. Your explanation helped me understanding these DataGrids

Comment: @AwkwardCoder I'll write my questions better in future, thank you

Comment: @MorgoZ It worked. But now I cannot scroll, even with `ScrollViewer` and `StackPanel`. Answer this question, and I'll mark a answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use a `ScrollViewer` and a `StackPanel`. Put them around your DataGrid:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid>
            ///Content goes here...
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Height="Auto" ....></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In your `DataGrid`, you'll need a `(DataGrid.)Template`:

```
<DataGrid RowHeaderWidth="0">
    <DataGrid.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter />
                <ItemsPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Template>
</DataGrid>
```

Now, the DataGrid uses the `ScrollViewer` to enable scrolling.